# HTTP Get request SQL server web API

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am working on the backend of my website and I need to get specific information from my SQL Server.

For this I use the HTTP Get request. But I don't want to use the ID to get the information, but I want to type a name to search the database for that name.

This is my current code:

```
// GET: api/Users/Toolname
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Users>> Get(string Tool_Name)
    {
        var info = await _context.Tool_Registration.FindAsync(Tool_Name);

        if (info == null)
        {
            return info;
        }

        return info;
    }
```

So when I enter a Tool name it should return all the information where the Tool name is used. But it doesn't return anything. When I change it back to ID then I can search for the ID and it returns the information I want.

How do I make a correct HTTP get request for my Tool Name?

Edit:

More information about the model:

```
public class Users
{
    [Key]
    public int Tool_ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(MAX)")]
    public string Tool_Name { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "int")]
    public int UUID { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(MAX)")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(MAX)")]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

}
```

Tool_Registration is the name of the table. The module exists of the column names.

Edit 2:

This is my complete controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using iTools_Web_API.Models;

namespace iTools_Web_API.Controllers
{



 [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UsersController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly UsersContext _context;

    public UsersController(UsersContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/Users/{UserId}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Users>> GetUserById(int UserId)
    {
        var user = await _context.Tool_Registration.FindAsync(UserId);
        return Ok(user);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/Users/")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Users>>> GetUsers(string Tool_Name)
    {
        IEnumerable<Users> users;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Tool_Name))
            users = await _context.Tool_Registration.ToListAsync();
        else
            users = await _context.Tool_Registration.Where(tr => tr.Tool_Name == Tool_Name).ToListAsync();
        return Ok(users);
    }

    // PUT: api/Users/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
    // more details, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754.
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PutUsers(int id, Users users)
    {
        if (id != users.Tool_ID)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        _context.Entry(users).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!UsersExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return NoContent();
    }

    // POST: api/Users
    // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
    // more details, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754.
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Users>> PostUsers(Users users)
    {
        var Tool = await _context.Tool_Registration.FindAsync(users.Tool_Name);
        if(Tool != null)
        {
            return Tool;
        }
        else
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
    }

    // DELETE: api/Users/5
    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Users>> DeleteUsers(int id)
    {
        var users = await _context.Tool_Registration.FindAsync(id);
        if (users == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        _context.Tool_Registration.Remove(users);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return users;
    }

    private bool UsersExists(int id)
    {
        return _context.Tool_Registration.Any(e => e.Tool_ID == id);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: provide more details about `Tool_Registration`

Comment: From what I can tell, you haven't added any `Routes` to this endpoint? In your case it would be `[Route("api/Users/{Tool_Name?}")]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity Framework's `FindAsync` method returns a row based on a primary key. When you change the input from the ID to `Tool_Name` you are no longer passing the method the primary key. Thus you need to use another EF method such as `FirstOrDefault` to return the details based on the Tool_Name:

```
var info = await _context.Tool_Registration.FirstOrDefaultAsync( tr => tr.Tool_Name == Tool_Name);
```

You should also probably implement two endpoints: one to return a single User record based on the ID, and one to return multiple based on the Tool_Name filter:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{UserId}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Users>> GetUserById(int UserId)
{
    var user = await _context.Tool_Registration.FindAsync(UserId);
    return Ok(user);
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("")]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Users>>> GetUsers(string Tool_Name)
{
    IEnumerable<Users> users;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Tool_Name))
        users = await _context.Tool_Registration.ToListAsync();
    else
        users = await _context.Tool_Registration.Where(tr => tr.Tool_Name == Tool_Name).ToListAsync();
    return Ok(users);
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215365/discussion-on-answer-by-strickt01-http-get-request-sql-server-web-api).

Answer (score -1):

This is probably a routing issue. From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1) the default routing convention in asp.net MVC is:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

This gives comprehension of the `ID` parameter as part of the path. When the parameter name is changed this is not part of the route, so the framework doesn't recognise that the Tool_Name path segment should be interpreted as an action parameter.

Requesting your new action in the form:

```
GET /api/Users?Tool_Name=toolname
```

should get you the right result, alternatively/additionally you can add another route:

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "Tool_Name",
        pattern: "{controller=Users}/{action=Get}/Tool_Name");
```